# Should we include firebase listener inside a RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Currently I have a RecyclerView adapter class which display a list of event with their event name and the host user image. I need to use firebase listener to get the right host (by using the host's user id) for their profile image, then place to each of the list item's imageView. I am trying to avoid getting the profile image by calling the firebase listener inside RecyclerView, but I couldn't figure out a better idea to get the data. Can anyone guide me through this?

Below is the RecyclerView adapter class, where the firebase listener is placed in the onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull partyViewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Party model){
           getUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        for (DataSnapshot datas : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            try {
                                GlideApp.with(context).load(datas.child("uri").getValue(String.class))
                                        .placeholder(R.drawable.blank_picture)
                                        .into(holder.mUserImg);
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Log.d("adapter", "onBindViewHolder: "+ e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        GlideApp.with(context).load(R.drawable.blank_picture)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.blank_picture)
                                .into(holder.mUserImg);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.w("adapter", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                }
            });
}
```

Edited:
firebase structure:

Event data
[image: Event data]

User data

[image: User data]

Comment: can you share your database structure ?

Comment: @50_Seconds_Of_Coding i just updated the structure, root/party.. and root/users/normal...

Comment: What are you storing in the RecyclerView and why do you need an extra listener?

Comment: Why don't you get the user data together with the party data and merge them before loading the data in the recyclerview?

Comment: Frankly speaking what you are trying to achieve by avoiding one extra listener, is foregin key and joins concept from SQL. But the problem with the firebase is they dont provide API level method for the same.

Comment: Now what you can do is fetch the *all the data* to your device and then perform the join operation on this two trees and then pass it to recyclerview

Comment: But problem with this approach is you have to fecth all the data to your device first, so you can't use limit query

Comment: So adding a extra listener remains one of your option on client side. But issue with this, is the cost of operation, that is if you go for blaze plan and in future your application scales. Imagine the read operations, it will be counted for each child node.

Comment: Better method will be instead of creating a separate node (parent) for the data, try to add the data under same node (parent).

Comment: And if you want to maintain separate nodes (parent), only option remains is duplication, what will you do is create duplicate entries in second node which are necessary to fetch from first node.

Comment: Sadly thats the limitation for firebase realtime database as well as firestore too

Comment: @50_Seconds_Of_Coding yes i guess if I really want to get rid of extra listener, I have to duplicate the necessary data...anyway, thank you for guiding me :)

Comment: Sure, if you want to develop more complex applications and stick to BaaS (No SQL), you should go with Mongo DB instead.